# Replacing a 5V female barrel connector on USB hub with female USB micro

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, usb, usb-hub

Is it possible (and relatively easy) to replace a 5 V power plug (barrel connector) on a USB hub with a standard USB Micro power-only female?  If so, is there anything special (besides hooking up the +5 V and GND connections)?

I have been trying to find some information about it, but I haven't been able to.  I keep reading stuff about using a 200Ω resistor between pins 2 and 3, but that is for making a custom plug (the USB micro male).  Would that also apply to the female?

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to this kind of stuff.  I can handle a soldering iron, but I'm quite new to actual electrical engineering concepts.

Some clarification (based on the comments):

- This is to swap out the barrel connector for the power to the USB hub - nothing to do with the actual USB ports that will be linked.
- The USB hub is a [Belkin F5U404](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BDV0LO0), which makes for a killer little hub for the Raspberry Pi Zero. Problem is the power plug was faulty (if I wiggle it barely it powers off) and quite frankly, when I got half a dozen Pi Zeros, I would like to be able to plug them into any phone charger and not carry around the power cord.
- I picked up some [USB Micro Female connectors](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1829) from Adafruit
- The standard power supply for the USB Hub is 5 V / 2600 mA - I'm hoping my 2000 or 2500 mA USB plugs will be sufficient.

Comment: is the purpose to provide external supply ?

Comment: Doing this will likely violate the USB power negotiation specifications, depending on where you source your upstream power. Do you not have the ability to use bus power on the USB hub already?

Comment: If this is the external power input to a usb hub, then yes, all you really need is V+ and Gnd. Pretty much most usb power adapters are dumb chargers and don't need to be enabled or anything,  so you can plug it right in. You are only using this as a convenient 5V source.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  I added some clarification to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Passerby thanks, so the bit about putting a resistor between D+ and D- pins on the male I believe was just to make that device get identified as a power plug (or something), and no data would come across. Just to double-clarify: you're saying there's nothing special about the female.  Just the two pins, and keep all other pins disconnected?  Thanks again! :)

Comment: The resistor across the two data pins are for a Dedicated Charging Port identification. The charger has it. Not the device to be charged. No need here. Just use the V+ and Gnd,  no other pins.

Comment: Thanks a lot - gonna go give it a shot right now.  I realize my question was kinda all-over-the-place, but you nailed it as far as what I was looking for.  If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: If the power connector isn't making connection, it probably has a faulty solder joint.   Fixing that joint is easier than wiring to another connector.

Comment: It seems to be on the wire right where the little box part that has the prongs for the wall connects with the cable.  Regardless, I the connector and want to replace it with usb micro anyway.  Thanks

Comment: Figure out how you are going to make reliable electrical and mechanical connection to the micro USB jack *and then accomplish and test that* before you start modifying the hub.  Personally, I'd be more tempted to come up with a cable to go between a USB A socket, and the DC barrel jack of the hub, which could remain unmodified.

Comment: The so-called "1.3mm" barrel jacks are very flimsy in my experience. Their mating plug (cable side) is always loose on almost every device I've seen. This must be an OEM lousy job of mechanical matching between jacks an plugs.

Comment: @AliChen yes as has been mine.  I have two USB hubs with that type of plug - one Chinese no-name from Ebay and this Belkin one.  Both have arrived in a (somewhat) non-functioning state - and it's always been because of that.  The belkin is the power adapter itself - the Chinese one is the power plug on the hub.  Either one will work with enough wiggling.  The Chinese power adapter works fine on the Belkin - it really just boils down to me hating that cheap jack and wanting a more "standard" plug to use with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use of micro-USB receptacle for powering a 4-port USB hub is a poor idea. The official contact rating for micro-USB matching pair is 1.8A only, which is technically insufficient to power all four ports to full capacity.

Regarding the specific questions:

(a)  replacing the power jack barrel with u-USB is possible, but is not easy, unless you will glue the u-USB or secure it somehow else, and use fly wires, since PCB footprints are totally incompatible;

(b) the **under 200Ω** connection between D+/D- is one of the charging port identification signatures, on the port which supplies power, which will be on the other end of your cable. On receiving end nothing should should be connected to D+/D-.