# Change laptop 5.5mm barrel connector

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, laptop

I'm looking to replace the female 5.5mm barrel jack connector on my
laptop with a female USB C connector. The replacement USB C port need
only provide power and nothing further. I'm not sure how to go about
this. I've never modified anything electronic before, soldering is new
to me.

The model of the laptop is a 
[Lenovo X230t](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x230t/)

My hope is that the scope of the project is just:

- Open up laptop.
- Remove old jack.
- Solder on USB C jack.
- Get USB-C AC adaptor with matching DC output for laptop.

What I want from y'all are:

- An understanding of the difficulty of doing this: the time and money
  costs of this project. Time covers any time spent doing the actual
  task and learning skills that I'd need to learn to do it competently.
- Is the project more complicated than the steps listed above? If so,
  how?

Some suggested contributions to satisfy these goals are:

- Pointing out difficulties that I will face outside of the above
  listed hopeful project scope. For instance, saying that I'd have to
  modify something on my motherboard, or I'd have to add something else
  after the USB C female port so that power from the port can go to the
  motherboard. This will help me ask further questions about both the
  time and money costs of dealing with these problems.
- Giving a solution to one of the pointed out difficulties and giving
  some estimate of the time/money costs involved in carrying out the
  solution.
- Helping me understand the skills required to carry out this plan (I
  assume soldering is one). If the project would involve more detailed
  knowledge than "connect this wire to that other wire", then I'm out of
  my depth, and I wouldn't know what to do or where to look to gain
  those competencies.
- Giving a the broad strokes of a plan to work this project, from
  start to finish. That's

  - The steps of the plan, stated in general terms ("solder this",
    "buy that", "attach blah blah thing"). I ask only for broad
    strokes because detailed plans are time consuming to create, and
    it would be easier to prepare some of these details in conjunction
    with me, so you can get an idea of the sort of things I can
    do/learn quickly.
  - A list of the materials involved and where to obtain them (as
    best as you can). If you can't provide a location, please try to
    provide an approximate price and/or the sort of retailer that may
    sell the item (like "hobby shop" or "old pc parts store" or
    something).

This is a somewhat similar question:
[Replacing a 5V female barrel connector on USB hub with female USB micro](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253213/replacing-a-5v-female-barrel-connector-on-usb-hub-with-female-usb-micro)

PS: Another possibility might be some sort of adaptor from USB C male
to 5.5mm barrel male that would provide the correct amount of power.
This is okay, but not desired. I have to replace the barrel jack
itself on my laptop anyway. The plug of my AC adaptors doesn't hold
well in them. But if this method is significantly easier than
replacing the connector altogether... then I'll probably do that.

Edit: My original intent was to get/construct a magnetic connector for an older laptop. To that end, I've found the following sources, which make these connectors for a barrel-jack-style plug:

- https://www.instructables.com/id/MagSafe-for-the-Rest-of-Us-A-DIY-Magnetic-Power-A/
- https://www.instructables.com/id/ThinkSafe:-A-Magnetic-Power-Connector-for-Thinkpad/
- https://www.instructables.com/id/Magnetic-Laptop-power-connector/

I was surprised to find these, given that magnetic connectors for power cables are supposed to have a very broad patent on them.

Comment: I am **very** skilled at modding electronic devices including laptops. I have changed / modded DC jacks on laptops. Would I attempt what you ask above: **Nope**. Why not? Because even if you pulled it off the connector will break eventually. The case isn't designed for a USB-C connector. The connection will be fiddly and a potential fire hazard.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This is a very broad question. To be effective on this site, it is important to ask specific, concise questions. This not only makes it easier for people to answer, but also helps the post provide help for others in the future.

Comment: @Daniel Can you give me some pointers on how to be concise? I spent around 30 minutes drafting that question so that I WAS concise. There's a whole section at the bottom about what sort of concrete answers to give. Did you read that?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks! Could you explain what it is about the case that's not designed for a USB-C connector? Why must the connection be fiddly and a potential fire hazard? Does the USB-C connector run too hot or something? Is there some sort of workaround to this issue?

Comment: This is very long question describing what is in the end a simple soldering job as an epic Project. What it lacks, however, is any reasonable goal. Which makes it from epic project into badly thought-through idea. The whole page of text and not a single hint of what exactly you want  to achieve by this.

Comment: @Maple Thanks! I think I can answer your question, though I'm confused by your feedback. Why is it not enough that this is reasonable to _me_? I'm also unsure as to why "change the connectors" isn't an "exact" goal to acheive.
I've searched for information on this in-and-out over the course of a year. I've never found valuable sources on it. The original goal was for a magnetic connector. Since those are patented I figured I'd have to get an existing magnetic connector of some kind and make it work with the laptop. I found that USB C cords have magnetic connectors now.

Comment: @Maple I really hope this is a simple soldering job (though others have suggested otherwise), but I haven't found enough useful information to suggest whether it would or wouldn't be. I'm here to draw upon the information that y'all have, and thus I've provided specific forms of helpful information. Because I haven't been able to find it anywhere else. The closest forms of this question that I've found elswhere all have answers of, "haha, good luck pal." That's _not helpful_. I'm definitely not looking for that here.

Comment: I recommend reading on [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). "change the connectors" is not a problem, it is your solution to some problem you failed to mention. And just FYI, the cheap magnetic cables with USB C plug flooding the market, claiming to deliver 7-10A charge are nowhere close to that and usually just safety hazards

Comment: @Maple I've read the link. That's true, I suppose. This is a case of that. I'll consider taking this question down since I've gotten nothing but "no don't do this" and downvotes without at least a probing question like yours (thanks for that, by the way). However, what if I really just wanted to change the connectors? Why is that question not valuable in it's own right? What if I still want an answer to this question regardless? I'm left at a bit of a loss as to how asking questions here is supposed to function.

Comment: Here is an example of actual problem: "The jack in my laptop <insert model here> is broken, how can I replace it?" This can be answered, although not on this site. Or "I want to replace stock power connector with magnetic one for convenience. Here is the connector I found <insert link to connector>. Can I use it?". This also can be answered, and many people here would be glad to help.

Comment: @Maple I'm not getting it, still. Is the 1st example better because something is broken, whereas my connector is still fine? As for the 2nd example, that sounded off-topic for this site. I would've asked something closer to that, but where's the "electrical engineering" in "plug that attaches magnetically"? It's got little to do with the plug itself and more to do with how it attaches. It feels like going to a car stackexchange about about repairing/changing the hinge on a hood. It's a hinge, and not really a problem specific to cars. Any hinge repair pointers would do.

Comment: @Maple I tried to make this as on-topic as I thought I could because most other similar-ish questions (in other places) ended in "haha, good luck with that." It took me a _year_ to think about posting about this specifically because I didn't seem to find anyone asking similar enough questions elsewhere, or the responses were just unhelpful.

Comment: "I'm not getting it, still" is correct. The first example is better because it presents actual problem and provides enough information (laptop model) to answer it. It _is_ off-topic however, since questions on repair consumer electronic are off-topic here. On the other hand second example can pass (barely) as on-topic because it involves modification of the device, which is engineering problem.

Comment: @Maple Fair enough, I guess. My question involves both of those things though. I specified the laptop model in the question, and my quesiton is about modification of a device. So... what do I do from here on out? Do I delete the question? It's not terribly useful at this point. I got some helpful-ish answers on roadblocks, but at this point I doubt I'm going to get any elaboration on how to get around those roadblocks, which is what I _really_ wanted (and specifically asked for).

Comment: There is no need to delete the question. The usual approach is once you figured out what is it your really want edit your question with the following in mind: a) begin by clearly stating the problem/end goal; b) keep it short; c) provide enough information. models of the devices, links to the components/datasheets; d) show _briefly_ research you've already done.  At this point your question is OK on c) and d), falls short on a) and completely fails on b). That is the reason you are getting those -1 votes, I believe

Comment: @Maple Thanks for taking the time to talk this through with me. I'm not 100% finished with this idea, though, and it seems this isn't the place for it; what I needed was an extended discussion to show me the difficulties of the project and how I might get around them. The bulk of the question text just specifies concrete answers to this broad discussion, so that it would fit the site. If this question has "failed", it's because this isn't the place for it. If you'd be so kind, what _is_ the place for this question? Is there a forum where I could have that talk?

Comment: @Maple I get the feeling that a question not fitting in here translates direclty to "bad question". So Just in case your answer includes "better research" or "proper planning": I asked this because information was scarce/inaccessible to a beginner; how well could I have thought this out without good information to go on? Perhaps information was scarce because this is a bad idea. _I don't care_. Let me judge that "badness" for myself. The point of this question was to gather enough information to make my own judgment.

Comment: As you can see, my intentions were the opposite of judging you. I was trying to prevent this from being closed, which eventually has happened anyway. At this point I can only recommend you to fix a) and b) from my comment above if you want this to be reopened.

Comment: @Maple I could see that, thank you. It's better than what I came up with. I didn't say thanks because the rules say not to. I think closing this is best. After doing some reading on what posts should be like, every SE site says "no discussions". But that's what I need.  Referencing your answer, do I buy a 3-pin connector because the original jack had 3 pins? Does it matter which wires touch which pins (it should, right?), etc. I only know enough about electronics to guess through those things and cross my fingers. I don't know enough to even troubleshoot my work (way more important).

Comment: @Maple I came here to rely on the experience of others because I have very little (for now). That's not what this place is about. I can't just say, "Here's the general idea, help. What do I need to move forward?" I'm supposed to already have specific, answerable questions... which requires that I know what I'm doing. Which I don't. That's why I asked earlier if you knew of a place where I could request this sort of discussion, and it wouldn't be frowned upon. Maybe some forum or IRC channel or something. That's a question for anyone, really, that stumbles upon this comment.

Comment: You can use 3-pin connector if it is polarized (i.e. does not allow wrong connection, just as your original plug). You can use 5 or more -pin non-polarized connectors if you wire them symmetrically, e.g. like this: -, +, signal, +, -. In either case primary considerations should be power ratings and method of mounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My hope is that the scope of the project is just:

There are several problematic points in your "scope of the project". Let's go point-by-point:

> (1) Open up laptop.

Okay, no problem here.

> (2) Remove old jack.

Okay, doable as well, with certain care and right tools like hot air pen (since the connector might have through-hole legs across a thick ~12-layer PCB.

> (3) Solder on USB C jack.

Here the problems start. Type-C footprint is very tight, and there is 2500% probability that you can't fit the old footprint. You will need to use some interposer mini-board, and glue it somehow into the old place. Mechanical properties of this rework will be highly questionable, and the new Type-C connector will likely fall off after 10-15 insertions. But this is still doable. However it won't be functional unless you add proper pull-downs and other sophisticated electronics to it, see below.

> (4) Get USB-C AC adaptor with matching DC output for laptop.

Now this is a real problem. Your laptop has likely something as 19-20-V input for normal operation. If you plan to get a "USB-C AC-DC adapter", this is not going to happen, even it would list "matching DC output" as one of its output options. The reason is that any Type-C adapter-charger must have a Power Delivery negotiation protocol in place, to move form the default-safe initial +5V level to higher power profiles. More, initially a Type-C charger-adapter won't output ANY VOLTAGE at all until the Type-C cable will see 5.1k pull-down on CC lines (which you should have after attaching your new Type-C connector).

The second hurdle will be PD, Power Delivery. Unless you get a set of special ICs, hook them up to CC line and program them for desired PD profile (19-20 V 3 A or something), a normal Type-C adapter won't give you the desired power.

One thing you can do is to get the fixed-voltage (your old) AC-DC adapter (19 V 3 A) and replace the native barrel plug with Type-C plug. However, in this case you are seriously risking to fry many other Type-C gadgets if somebody accidentally will plug your modified self-made Type-C charger into them, at least Type-C smartphones will be 98% fried, since they wouldn't have the tolerance to 20-V profile.

ONE MORE: The ThinkPad X230T laptop has three-pin connector,

[image]

The third (center) pin is used for power identification of the adapter. I am not sure which method is used, but you will need to emulate proper conditions (analog level or serial protocol) before your laptop will resort to full functionality.

I feel somehow that at this point you will abandon this project, so the IC sourcing and pricing won't be needed.

Comment: At the moment, your suspicions are correct; I cannot pick up this project any time soon without some extended guidance. I want this to work well, so I'd need to have a discussion about getting around the hurdles you (and others) presented, and some guidance on where/how to get the skills to pull it off. At the moment, it seems this isn't the place for that (or my topic doesn't warrant it), nor do I know of one. FWIW, this is exactly the sort of answer I wanted; you broke down the difficulties I'd face in a more complete manner. Thank you, really.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to replace the female 5.5mm barrel jack connector [...]
>   laptop is a Lenovo X230t

Not a good idea. These jacks are 3-pin connectors (with an inside metal layer), and use the 3rd pin to detect the PSU type. Without the proper communication on this line, the laptop might not charge at all.

> The replacement USB C port need only provide power and nothing further.

USB-C does no loger provide power by default, unfortunatlely. You need active electronics (that is different from lenovo propritary PSU connector) in order to tell an USB-C PSU to turn on the 20V output.

> I have to replace the barrel jack itself on my laptop anyway.

The DC-In connector is **not** soldered to the motherboard, and can be replaced relatively easy - just not with an USB-C one.

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin with saying that I agree with everything in @ale..chenski answer. Type C USB connector is absolutely bad fit for this application, but that was an answer to your actual question.

I'd like to tackle it from different point. If your question had been "how to replace original connector with magnetic one" the answer would be different. If you simply type "magnetic connector" into google search you'd see hundreds of pictures like these:

[image]

Links: [6-pin](https://www.hacker-motor-shop.com/Wing-and-fuselage-connectors/-magnetic-connect/-magnetic-connect-wing-connectors-6-pin.htm?shop=hacker_e&SessionId=&a=article&ProdNr=A85261&p=9239), [5-pin](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Automotive-5-pogo-pin-gold-plated_60707814372.html), [3-pin](http://cfconn.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008844589336/pdtl/Magnetic-connector/1158231175/Magnetic-Cable-Connector.htm). Also the [last company](http://cfconn.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008844589336/pdtl/Magnetic-connector/1158231175/Magnetic-Cable-Connector.htm) has tons of different connectors, many designed specifically for laptop charging.

As you can see, it is possible to find good quality connector *rated for your application* and most important, much *easier to solder* than USB type C.

Don't forget to look for either *polarized* connectors or 5+ pin ones. Polarized connectors won't allow you to plug it in wrong direction. 5-pin (and up) connectors can be wired symmetrically, so the insertion direction does not matter.

What you can do then, is:

- find a place on your laptop with enough clearance inside to safely mount the connector without touching anything else;
- figure out the way to *securely* attach connector to laptop. Screws are the best, epoxy is OK. Solder to tiny PCB and then glue it inside also works;
- Mount the connector and solder 3 wires between it and original connector. Now you have an option to use either one;
- Buy spare Lenovo AC adapter. Cut off its connector and solder magnetic plug instead. This way you will be using exactly the same adapter as your original one, so laptop would not know the difference, and you wouldn't worry about mismatched power requirements.

This is not an especially easy project, but certainly doable and most of all, it at least makes sense.

Comment: Yep, if the original idea was about magnetic connector, then MacBook 2007 had it. You can go to a junk computer store and get the Macbook, and chargers are still available, cut the cable and adapt.